# incoming music stream of 912kHz stutters, lower kHz don't

Tags: audio, streaming

I live in the UK and have a music subscription with Presto Music https://www.prestomusic.com a great selection of classical music and jazz.  It comes via my router and an ethernet cable to my Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB connected by HDMI output to my TV with nice speakers.  But I have found that streaming encoded at 192kHz is too much for my Pi to process, and it stutters.  Up to 96kHz it had been ok but newer albums are streamed at 192kHz.

This happens in Raspian Chromium and also Ubuntu or Manjaro with Firefox.  Tweaking browser settings doesn't help, I had a go at installing ffmpeg which made it worse.  By a process of elimination I find the only factor causing the stuttering is the kHz of the stream.

I opened VLC and tried to play the stream through that by copying the URL of the music but it didn't work.

If I listen on my PC or my iPhone there is no problem.

I have done some research but not found an answer, or one that I understand;  I'm a beginner.  Do I need to install more software?   Would a USB-DAC solve the problem?  I'd prefer that to a HAT because the Pi is in a nice FLIRC case.  Most DAC seem to be for headphones but I only to connect to my TV's line-in.

Hope this is the right section to post in.  Please can anyone advise?

Thanks, Matthew

Comment: Are you running any other *demanding* apps on your RPi?

Comment: not running any other apps just Firefox to log-in to my streaming account and select what to listen to, thanks

Comment: Have you run (for example) `htop` to get an idea of resource utilization?

Comment: yes, when playing 96kHz the four bars at the top are mostly green with some red at the ends, music is not interrupted,  
and when playing 192kHz they quickly go mostly red which coincides with the stutter

Comment: the MPEG4-SLS codec is what is coming in from Presto Music who use Orastream

Comment: Well there you go - sounds like you've got your answer?

Comment: so the RPi4B isn't able to perform at that level... would overclocking it help? or can the RPi5 do it?

Comment: NOTE: When you want to reply to a comment **from someone (like me) who commented to your post (Question)**, you **preface your comment** with (for example, `@seamus`). This insures that the website informs the correct person that you have replied to their comment. You'll find that the "auto-complete" feature here works quite well for addressing comments :)

Comment: Yeah - perhaps it's not able to perform at that level. Not an audiophile myself, but 192kHz sampling rate sounds a bit *"top-heavy"* to me given the limits of the human ear. I've no idea whether RPi 5 is capable of handling that or not, but it is quite a bit faster than RPi4... but I'd invest the £6 for the fan if I were going to try it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I bought a HiFiBerry DAC+ and a bigger case for the Pi and this solved the problem.  Enjoying the music!